# Unable to get my chat list on Gmail and no pictures in Facebook

Tags: windows-7, gmail, facebook

I'm not able to see any pictures in my Facebok account but when I'm trying to open one of my friend's account it was working fine and showing everything as usual.

Also I'm not able to get my chat list on Gmail and showing message

> Unable to reach Gmail. Please check your internet connection or company's network settings.

But the internet connection is working fine. I can guess that it might be some network setting fault but I'm newbie to face this kind of issues so can anyone please help me to figure out this issue?

I have tried 2 browsers and am on Windows 7. This is a fresh install.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser... First questions: does `www.google.com` open properly? Can you refresh that page with the `SHIFT` key pressed and then does it come up properly? Does some search string like `"Hello World"` return results successfully?

Comment: Hi Nik, thanks for your quick reply. Yes google is opening properly and also search strings comes successfully.

Comment: Oliver...sorry but can you tell me why are you've made down mark to my question...I've just posted the issue which I'm facing.

Comment: Can you clarify the question please. When you say open his account, do you mean logging in with his credentials? Or do you mean visiting his page?

Answer (score 1):

I had a near identical issue to this - the pictures on a website not loading was due to my anti-banner in Kasperksy Anti Virus.

Due to your second issue also being network related, my money is on a firewall / internet security issue.

If you can and feel confident to do so, disable your internet security and try it. This will at least rule it out.

Or, open your browser without any plugins (like a safe mode) or disable the internet security plugins.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your quick reply, I'd just format my PC completely and didn't install any security. I've direct started the internet connection so I think there is not security reason for this issue, is there any possibility for this?

Comment: What operating system are you on? Also, please try a different browser.

Comment: I'm on Widnows 7 and I've tried on chrome too but it didn't work on chrome too.

Comment: Are you able to try to open your account on another machine? If your friend's account works fine then it rules out the PC / browser (maybe).

Comment: I'm able to access my account from another machine...

Comment: But if there is any problem with my account then the issue should come at another PC too but its working fine at another Machine...

Comment: I wonder if it has left cookies or similar on your machine and can't read it correctly. Try deleting all your internet files (or use CCleaner)